# Python calling unwanted function from dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

When I run my program which is featured below. The program runs the first function in the dictionary rather than the function of the folder which contains a file that has to be converted. Can someone please explain to me why it is executing a function that is not being called?

```
for folder in os.listdir('Z:/Buchhaltung/Netsuite/Thomas/1. File Converter/Upload Rough Files/'):
  if os.path.isdir('Z:/Buchhaltung/Netsuite/Thomas/1. File Converter/Upload Rough Files/'+str(folder)):
      if len(os.listdir('Z:/Buchhaltung/Netsuite/Thomas/1. File Converter/Upload Rough Files/' + str(folder))) >= 1:
         for file in os.listdir('Z:/Buchhaltung/Netsuite/Thomas/1. File Converter/Upload Rough Files/' + str(folder)):
            if '(DONE)' not in str(file) and str(file).startswith('.') == False:
                pathvariable = 'Z:/Buchhaltung/Netsuite/Thomas/1. File Converter/Upload Rough Files/' + str(folder) + '/' + str(file)
                outputpathvariable = 'Z:/Buchhaltung/Netsuite/Thomas/1. File Converter/Export CSV Files/' + str(folder) + '/' + 'Converted - ' + str(file)
                folderFunctionDict = {
                    "1800 - Kreissparkasse Heinsberg KSK1":ExportKSK1(path=pathvariable,outputpath=outputpathvariable),
                    "1801 - Kreissparkasse Heinsberg GBP": 0,
                    "1802 - Kreissparkasse Heinsberg CZK": 0,
                    "1803 - Kreissparkasse Heinsberg USD": 0,
                    "1804 - Kreissparkasse Heinsberg KSK2":ExportKSK2(path=pathvariable, outputpath=outputpathvariable),
                }
                folderFunctionDict.get(str(folder))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "function of the folder"?

Comment: You're calling _two_ functions, and putting their return values in the dictionary.

Comment: @jonrsharpe how do I make the function only be called when this piece of code is ran: "folderFunctionDict.get(str(folder))" It is tracking folders and when a file is in the folder it is supposed to run the corresponding functoin

Comment: @matszwecja Each function corresponds to a folder. 1800 - Kreissparkasse Heinsberg KSK1 is the name of a folder. If this folder is filled with a file that does not contain the text "(DONE" it is supposed to call the function corresponding to that folder with as variables the paths of the file to be converted

Comment: When you write `ExportKSK2(path=pathvariable, outputpath=outputpathvariable)` when creating a dictionary, you are already calling the function. If you want to define a callable use just a function name without parentheneses.
You need to use only `ExportKSK1` and `ExportKSK2` in the dictionary and then when you want to call it you get the callable from a dictionary and provide it with arguments: `folderFunctionDict['folder'](path=pathvariable, outputpath=outputpathvariable)`
Also I'm not sure why you are redefining your dictionary in every iteration of the loop.

Comment: @matszwecja Thanks alot for this response! Helped me greatly. Reason for redefingen the dictionary every iteration is the fact that I haven't done any optimization yet. I'm a self though Python Dev and the chapter "Optimization" hasn't reached me yet :D